# Fixed Shipping Cost Within UK, Another Fixed Cost For Worldwide

Tags: shipping

I would like to charge a fixed £x to ship any number of items of any value to within the United Kingdom.

I would also like to charge a fixed £y to ship any number of items of any value to all other countries.

How do I set this up?

Comment: You can do this with fixed table rates and a lot of * in the table...

Comment: That's what I though I'd need to do. Can I put * in the country column as a default rate for every country, then specify one for the UK only?

Comment: I think the other way around... Let me post an answer :)

Comment: If you have this option available, please let me know I am looking for a company to ship from UK internationally based on moderate fixed rate (based on weight only, not on the dimensions). Thank you.

Comment: First: This is not an answer, it is a question. And second. I'm sorry, but it is off topic. We don't answer questions about logistic companies. We answer questions about magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. I don't know what magento's internal code for UK is, just look it up. But this should map what you want.

```
"Country","Region","Zip","Weight","Price"
"*", "*", "*", "0.0000", "5.0000"
"UK?? GBR??", "*", "*", "0.0000", "5.0000"
```